# Use Cauchy's Theorem to find $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\cos(x) - \cos(y)}{x^2 - y^2}$.

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm starting with Cauchy's theorem and I have this exercise... I don't understand how the theorem would help me in finding the limit.

> $$f(x,y)=\left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
>       \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\cos(x) - \cos(y)}{x^2 - y^2} & x \neq y \\
>       -\frac{1}{2} &  x=y\\
> \end{array} 
> \right.$$

Suggestions? Perhaps I just need to see how what the theorem states is applicable to this situation... thanks!

Comment: So what does the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem actually state?

Comment: @Ted https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy.27s_mean_value_theorem before I go on to plug in and replace variables I want to understand why and how it would help me in this example...

Comment: It seems to me you end up with a one-variable limit problem if you use $\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{g(x)-g(y)} = \dfrac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$.

Comment: Yes, but I still don't understand why this works, sorry... I have a multivariable function and now I'm looking at it as a one-variable limit. I see how this ends up being $\lim_{(c)\to(0)} \frac{-\sin(c)}{2c}=-1/2$ I don't understand how... I mean... if I weren't to use Cauchy's theorem... I would probably would try with a bunch of paths and when I'm convinced that I have a candidate for limit (haven't got any contradiction) I would prove it by definition... this looks like magic in a way, sorry if I'm too naive.

Comment: Check it carefully with a $\delta$-$\epsilon$ argument. Note that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$ and $c$ between $x$ and $y$ implies $|c|<\delta$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $x \neq y$, without lost of generality we could assume that $y<x$, then Cauchy's mean value theorem states that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous on the interval $[x,y]$, and $f$ and $g$ are differentiable on $(x,y)$ then there is $c \in (x,y)$ such that:

$$ \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{g(y)-g(x)}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} $$

In this case we have that $f(x)=cos(x)$ and $g(x)=x^2$, then there is $c \in (y,x)$:

$$\frac{cos(x)-cos(y)}{x^2-y^2}=\frac{-sin(c)}{2c} $$

Then if $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ since $c \in (x,y)$ then $c \to 0$:

$$lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{cos(x)-cos(y)}{x^2-y^2} = lim_{c \to 0}\frac{-sin(c)}{2c}=\frac{-1}{2} lim_{c \to 0}\frac{sin(c)}{c}=\frac{-1}{2}$$

Because $lim_{c \to 0}\frac{sin(c)}{c} = 1$

Answer (score 6):

**HINT:  Without The Mean Value Theorem:**

Use the [Prosthaphaeresis Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis#Reverse_identities)

$$\cos(x)-\cos(y)=-2\sin\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)$$

Then write

$$\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(y)}{x^2-y^2}=-2\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)}{x+y}\right)\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)}{x-y}\right)$$

---

**HINT:  With The Mean Value Theorem:**

If $x<y$, there exists a number $\xi\in (x,y)$ such that

$$\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(y)}{x^2-y^2}=-\frac{\sin(\xi)}{2\xi}$$

If $y<x$, there exists a number $\eta\in (y,x)$ such that

$$\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(y)}{x^2-y^2}=-\frac{\sin(\eta)}{2\eta}$$